# Consume topics while acting as a https service to handle callback

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

[image]ect ?

Can a single Kafka Client consume multiple topics and act as a HTTP server at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Kafka clients don't have to be standalone processes and frequently are embedded in other apps.

KsqlDB, for example, already is a consumer that offers an HTTP REST API for pull/push queries from any topic you've setup from the cluster

Comment: Hi can you please share any references implementing this using FAstapi or python ?

Comment: Install and Import aiokafka in your Fastapi code and run a consumer. What specific issues are you having?

Comment: I am having issue using fastapi server and consuming (confluent-cloud) at the same time

Comment: What specific issues? Create a new post with a [mcve] of your code, please